# Android BottomSheet adapt/shrink related map view

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, bottom-sheet

Trying to mimic the current google maps Bar at the bottom.
I failed so hard and tried so much; CollapsingToolbar, BottomSheet, custom libs.

**What I want:** Making the map view adapt it's size and camera when the BottomSheet is sliding, so that the bottom sheet does not slide over the map but instead the map fits in the space that is left.

Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA9L4WOb7v0) to see what I mean (And I don't mean the zoom functionality)

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Yes, I used a BottomSheet to slide, expand and collapse my content, and kept the map behind. To adapt the map (size and camera centered) I put some code in the BottomSheets onSlide, and in its onStateChanged. Both can be done by just adapting the map padding accordingly. And it looks smooth and cool ;-)

Comment: can you share a snippet of the map and the bottomsheet sliding ?

Comment: @ralphgabb see full answer below.

Comment: @EssenceBlue will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The [BottomBar library](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)  I used is deprecated. But perhaps my code gives you an idea how it could be done.

I reacted to onSlide events of the BottomSheet like this:

```
@Override
public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    switch (bssBehavior.getState()) {
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
            setMapPaddingBotttom(slideOffset);
            searchVM.map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastValidMapCenter));
            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
            setMapPaddingBotttom(slideOffset);
            searchVM.map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastValidMapCenter));
            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
            break;
    }
```

And smoothly resized the map by changing its padding. For calculating it accordingly I used sth. like this.

```
private void setMapPaddingBotttom(Float offset) {
    //From 0.0 (min) - 1.0 (max)
    Float maxMapPaddingBottom = bsExpanded - bsCollapsed;
    //left,top,right,bottom
    searchVM.map.setPadding(0, 0, 0, Math.round(offset * maxMapPaddingBottom));
}
```

Comment: What are the variables bsExpanded - bsCollapsed ??

Comment: maxMapPaddingBottom is the maximal height of the maps padding in pixel, so by multiplying it with the percentage offset you get the respective pixel value. And bsExpanded is the height of the bottom sheet in pixels when it's expanded and bsCollapsed its size when collapsed and showing only a thin bar with e.g. some buttons or anything that indicated that you can swipe it up to expand it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example to achieve the effect that the Google Map's padding automatically resizes when a BottomSheet on top of it moves/slides.
This way the Google logo of the map always moves together with the bottomsheet.

1. Define your layout. We usually have an activity/fragment with MapFragment and a BottomSheet layout on top of it. Here is a sample with a full screen map:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="420dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Your bottom sheet's content-->

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2. Setup your activity or fragment. Similar to the idea posted by @EssenceBlue we use the `onSlide()` callback of the bottomsheet and adjust the map's bottom padding everytime.

```
class MapWithSheetActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var googleMap: GoogleMap? = null
    private var bottomSheetContainer: CoordinatorLayout? = null
    private var bottomSheetLayout: LinearLayout? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking_detail)
        this.bottomSheetLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.bottom_sheet)
        this.bottomSheetContainer = findViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(R.id.root_coordinator_layout)
        initMap()
        initBottomSheet()
    }

    private fun initMap() {
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as? SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
            this.googleMap = googleMap
        }
    }

    private fun initBottomSheet() {
        val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet))
        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :
            BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                when (bottomSheetBehavior.state) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING, BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> {
                        adjustMapPaddingToBottomSheet()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // No adjustment needed on other slide states.
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                // Needed only in case you manually change the bottomsheet's state in code somewhere.
                when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                        // Nothing to do here
                    }
                    else -> {
                        adjustMapPaddingToBottomSheet()
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }

    private fun adjustMapPaddingToBottomSheet() {
        googleMap?.let { map ->
            if (this.bottomSheetContainer != null && this.bottomSheetLayout != null) {
                val bottomSheetContainerHeight = this.bottomSheetContainer.height
                val currentBottomSheetTop = this.bottomSheetLayout.top
                map.setPadding(
                    0, // left
                    0, // top
                    0, // right
                    bottomSheetContainerHeight - currentBottomSheetTop // bottom
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```